# Angular universal view source not showing data from asp.net web API core

Tags: angular

Angular code to load the data

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient , private _title: Title,
    private _meta: Meta) {

    this.facts =   this.http.get('https://non-ssr-angular.firebaseio.com/facts.json');
    this.posts =   this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/api/post/ByMemberAsync/0/None`);
  }
```

Code to list which is returned API

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let fact of facts | async">
    {{fact.text}}
  </li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
    {{post.title}}
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- end snippet ->

When I view source through the browser it shows list only from (https://non-ssr-angular.firebaseio.com/facts.json) and wen API response show empty.

Output

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Please help anyone to fix it

Comment: What response are you getting from the call and do you have any error messages in the JS console in your browser?

Comment: this is testing site https://facts-1ab52.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: you can see data un the page but when you view source data from WEP API shows empty

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 19 Mar 2018 12:04:53 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinity=46b00f471cd74e0d2ed86afd100b04df09570f8099612a7c7a6d4e550fa14999;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=apicoderfirst.azurewebsites.net
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Comment: have you check this one working : this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/api/post/ByMemberAsync/0/None`)..what is value for `this.baseURL`

Comment: when you run it , put break point in your webapi and check breakpoint hitting or not ...

Comment: https://apicoderfirst.azurewebsites.net/api/post/ByMemberAsync/0/None

Comment: https://apicoderfirst.azurewebsites.net/api/post/ByMemberAsync/0/None

Comment: its working for me its givin me 9 objects in return what is issue at your end ??

Answer (score 0):

can you try out like this , you might get element in view source

```
<ul *ngIf="posts">
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
    {{post?.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure

in your app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})

in your component.ts

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
...
export class myComponent {
   facts:any;
   posts:any;
constructor(..){}
```

It's work for me: Angular CLI version (1.6.6)

Comment: data display on the page but in the browser source code data missing

Answer (score 0):

```
 import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
 ...
 facts:any=[];
 this.http.get('https://non-ssr-angular.firebaseio.com/facts.json').subscribe(data=>
 {this.facts=data});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to make it more useful to future readers